# Get data from server side by clicking Kendo UI Grid reload button

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid which loading data from ASP.NET controller and jquery, now i need to know, how to load data using reload button of Kendo UI Grid. Following the given code sendAjax("{}",url) function giving the JSON data and i bin it to kendoGrid's dataSource. but my requirements is when i click the reload button of Grid it'll load data from server side with same URL.

```
    function userTypeList() {
        var url="@Url.Action("GetUserTypeList", "UserType")";
        var data=sendAjax("{}",url);
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        columns: [
          {
              title: "Id",
              field: "Id"
          },
          {
              title: "Type",
              field: "Type"
          }
        ],
        dataSource: {
            data: data
        },
        editable: true
      });
    }

    userTypeList();
```

Comment: Have you tried by writing a single line of code?

Comment: From your question I cannot determine the actual and the expected behavior. Please describe what is seen and what you'd expect to see.

Comment: @PaulKertscher actually i have loaded Json data from ASP controller and bind it to kendo grid, working fine. now i want to click reload button which allocated footer. My requirements Once i click the reload button it'll load data from same url.

Comment: @sebu Please edit your question accordingly. A description of your requirements spread all over the comments won't be helpful at all.

Comment: @PaulKertscher Thanks. the summary of the question is how to work with Reload button of kendo grid. like click event. once i click it'll load data from server side.